# Command not found in container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Inside of a docker container I run a python script. My `Dockerfile` looks as follows

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /ingestion
COPY /services/bcp /ingestion/services/bcp

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/ingestion && \
    chmod +x /ingestion/bcp-build.sh && \
    /ingestion/bcp-build.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-m", "services.bcp"]
```

Inside of `bcp-build.sh` I install `bcp` tool for linux:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y curl

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list 

apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev 
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

To run the container I use `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
    bcp: 
        build: .
```

The python (a sample piece of code over here) looks like this:

```
import argparse

arg_parser: argparse = argparse. \
   ArgumentParser(
       description="Extract tables to CSV",
       usage="bcp.py [-h] [--database [str]]"
   )
required_args: argparse = arg_parser.add_argument_group("required arguments")
required_args.add_argument("--database", metavar="str", type=str, help="database from where to extract", required=True)

def foo():
   args: argparse = arg_parser.parse_args()
   database = args.database
   print(database)

   # build bcp cmd 
   cmd: str = f"bcp {database}.table out /tmp/ingestion/foo.csv"
   subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True) # execute it via subprocess

foo()
```

To create the image and use it, I run the following commands, `docker-compose up -d --build -t foo`. It works. But, when I try to execute `python` code it does not recognise the `bcp` command. It says **bcp command not found**. Could you please instruct, how to mitigate this issue?

The **exact** error message is **"bcp command not found"**.

Interestingly enough, when I run `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash foo`, and execute `bcp` then the command is available.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code that's actually causing the error, the actual text of the error message, and the Dockerfile (or `bcp-build.sh`) code that should cause the `bcp` tool to be present?

Comment: Hope the updated version helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install software in your image, you try to set an alternate path in `.bashrc`, but most common paths of running a Docker image never read those dotfiles.  The JSON-array form of `ENTRYPOINT` doesn't involve a shell at all, so nothing will ever read what you write out to the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

The `source` directives also have no effect: you're running it from a script so the environment variables that get set "expire" at the end of the `bcp-build.sh` script, and in any case a Dockerfile `RUN` directive doesn't notice or preserve changes in the environment.

If you need to modify environment variables in your image, you need to use the Dockerfile [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive.  (The only other thing that could change the container's environment is a script that runs at container startup time.)

```
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
```

In general Debian packages are required to install their software in the normal "system" directories, so you might file a bug that this support tool isn't being installed into `/usr/bin` like a normal binary would.

Comment: (If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`, you can `docker run --rm foo env` to check the process's environment, or `docker run --rm foo which bcp`, without the clumsy `--entrypoint` option.  Also consider what could happen if there is a `;` or other punctuation in the `--database` option to your script: `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` is a significant security issue.)

Comment: Many thanks! This solved my problem!!! Thanks a lot! Did not know that `source` does not work